# Rails testing not loading custom app config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, yaml

I am just learning Rails testing and I am not able to run ANY tests (even the "assert true" examples) because I get an error from an unrelated model not being able to load a custom config file variable.

My app has a custom config file loaded per this Railscast episode (http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file) in environment.rb

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root.to_s}/config/config.yml")[RAILS_ENV]
```

Thats fine in the normal app but in testing it is not loading it in a model:

```
    has_attached_file :photo,
                      :bucket => APP_CONFIG['s3_bucket']
```

Console error: `const_missing_from_s3_library': uninitialized constant Asset::APP_CONFIG (NameError)

(It should be noted that is NOT the same model I am trying to test but I guess the testing environment runs the whole app?)

What is different about the testing environment where it won't run environment.rb?

Comment: How does your config file looks like?

Comment: development:
    upgrade_price: 24
    root_url: http://localhost:3000/
    # etc
test:
     upgrade_price: 24
    root_url: http://localhost:3000/
    # etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out myself because Heroku and the testing environment have one thing in common:

**Heroku does NOT load environment.rb *before* the models and neither does the testing environment.**

All my controllers loaded the custom config vars mentioned above fine (in dev and Heroku) but as soon as a model tried to load one of those in Heroku or testing, it freaked out.

Lesson: for Heroku, use their [custom config vars](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) and reference it by ENV['name'] and add 'export name="whatever"' to your .bash_profile

(Or attempt [this](http://trevorturk.com/2009/06/25/config-vars-and-heroku/))

Answer (score 0):

I put mine at the bottom of application.rb (rails 3.2) and it worked fine on Heroku.